# Soft actor critic with discrete action space

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, reinforcement-learning

I'm trying to implement the soft actor critic algorithm for discrete action space and I have trouble with the loss function.

Here is the link from SAC with continuous action space:
https://spinningup.openai.com/en/latest/algorithms/sac.html

I do not know what I'm doing wrong.

The problem is the network do not learn anything on the cartpole environment.

The full code on github: https://github.com/tk2232/sac_discrete/blob/master/sac_discrete.py

Here is my idea how to calculate the loss for discrete actions.

### Value Network

```py
class ValueNet:
    def __init__(self, sess, state_size, hidden_dim, name):
        self.sess = sess

        with tf.variable_scope(name):
            self.states = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[None, state_size], name='value_states')
            self.targets = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[None, 1], name='value_targets')
            x = Dense(units=hidden_dim, activation='relu')(self.states)
            x = Dense(units=hidden_dim, activation='relu')(x)
            self.values = Dense(units=1, activation=None)(x)

            optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.001)

            loss = 0.5 * tf.reduce_mean((self.values - tf.stop_gradient(self.targets)) ** 2)
            self.train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss, var_list=_params(name))

    def get_value(self, s):
        return self.sess.run(self.values, feed_dict={self.states: s})

    def update(self, s, targets):
        self.sess.run(self.train_op, feed_dict={self.states: s, self.targets: targets})
```

In the Q_Network I'm gather the values with the collected actions

### Example

```
q_out = [[0.5533, 0.4444], [0.2222, 0.6666]]
collected_actions = [0, 1]
gather = [[0.5533], [0.6666]]
```

### gather function

```py
def gather_tensor(params, idx):
    idx = tf.stack([tf.range(tf.shape(idx)[0]), idx[:, 0]], axis=-1)
    params = tf.gather_nd(params, idx)
    return params
```

### Q Network

```py
class SoftQNetwork:
    def __init__(self, sess, state_size, action_size, hidden_dim, name):
        self.sess = sess

        with tf.variable_scope(name):
            self.states = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[None, state_size], name='q_states')
            self.targets = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[None, 1], name='q_targets')
            self.actions = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.int32, shape=[None, 1], name='q_actions')

            x = Dense(units=hidden_dim, activation='relu')(self.states)
            x = Dense(units=hidden_dim, activation='relu')(x)
            x = Dense(units=action_size, activation=None)(x)
            self.q = tf.reshape(gather_tensor(x, self.actions), shape=(-1, 1))

            optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.001)

            loss = 0.5 * tf.reduce_mean((self.q - tf.stop_gradient(self.targets)) ** 2)
            self.train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss, var_list=_params(name))

    def update(self, s, a, target):
        self.sess.run(self.train_op, feed_dict={self.states: s, self.actions: a, self.targets: target})

    def get_q(self, s, a):
        return self.sess.run(self.q, feed_dict={self.states: s, self.actions: a})
```

### Policy Net

```py
class PolicyNet:
    def __init__(self, sess, state_size, action_size, hidden_dim):
        self.sess = sess

        with tf.variable_scope('policy_net'):
            self.states = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[None, state_size], name='policy_states')
            self.targets = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[None, 1], name='policy_targets')
            self.actions = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.int32, shape=[None, 1], name='policy_actions')

            x = Dense(units=hidden_dim, activation='relu')(self.states)
            x = Dense(units=hidden_dim, activation='relu')(x)
            self.logits = Dense(units=action_size, activation=None)(x)
            dist = Categorical(logits=self.logits)

            optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.001)

            # Get action
            self.new_action = dist.sample()
            self.new_log_prob = dist.log_prob(self.new_action)

            # Calc loss
            log_prob = dist.log_prob(tf.squeeze(self.actions))
            loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.squeeze(self.targets) - 0.2 * log_prob)
            self.train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss, var_list=_params('policy_net'))

    def get_action(self, s):
        action = self.sess.run(self.new_action, feed_dict={self.states: s[np.newaxis, :]})
        return action[0]

    def get_next_action(self, s):
        next_action, next_log_prob = self.sess.run([self.new_action, self.new_log_prob], feed_dict={self.states: s})
        return next_action.reshape((-1, 1)), next_log_prob.reshape((-1, 1))

    def update(self, s, a, target):
        self.sess.run(self.train_op, feed_dict={self.states: s, self.actions: a, self.targets: target})
```

### Update function

```py
def soft_q_update(batch_size, frame_idx):
    gamma = 0.99
    alpha = 0.2

    state, action, reward, next_state, done = replay_buffer.sample(batch_size)
    action = action.reshape((-1, 1))
    reward = reward.reshape((-1, 1))
    done = done.reshape((-1, 1))
```

#### Q_target

[image]

```py
v_ = value_net_target.get_value(next_state)
q_target = reward + (1 - done) * gamma * v_
```

#### V_target

[image]

```py
next_action, next_log_prob = policy_net.get_next_action(state)
q1 = soft_q_net_1.get_q(state, next_action)
q2 = soft_q_net_2.get_q(state, next_action)
q = np.minimum(q1, q2)
v_target = q - alpha * next_log_prob
```

#### Policy_target

[image]

```py
q1 = soft_q_net_1.get_q(state, action)
q2 = soft_q_net_2.get_q(state, action)
policy_target = np.minimum(q1, q2)
```

Answer (score 7):

Since the algorithm is generic to both discrete and continuous policy, the key idea is that we need a discrete distribution that is reparametrizable. Then the extension should involve minimal code modification from the continuous SAC --- by just changing the policy distribution class.

There is one such distribution — the GumbelSoftmax distribution. PyTorch does not have this built-in, so I simply extend it from a close cousin which has the right rsample() and add a correct log prob calculation method. With the ability to calculate a reparametrized action and its log prob, SAC works beautifully for discrete actions with minimal extra code, as seen below.

```py
    def calc_log_prob_action(self, action_pd, reparam=False):
        '''Calculate log_probs and actions with option to reparametrize from paper eq. 11'''
        samples = action_pd.rsample() if reparam else action_pd.sample()
        if self.body.is_discrete:  # this is straightforward using GumbelSoftmax
            actions = samples
            log_probs = action_pd.log_prob(actions)
        else:
            mus = samples
            actions = self.scale_action(torch.tanh(mus))
            # paper Appendix C. Enforcing Action Bounds for continuous actions
            log_probs = (action_pd.log_prob(mus) - torch.log(1 - actions.pow(2) + 1e-6).sum(1))
        return log_probs, actions


# ... for discrete action, GumbelSoftmax distribution

class GumbelSoftmax(distributions.RelaxedOneHotCategorical):
    '''
    A differentiable Categorical distribution using reparametrization trick with Gumbel-Softmax
    Explanation http://amid.fish/assets/gumbel.html
    NOTE: use this in place PyTorch's RelaxedOneHotCategorical distribution since its log_prob is not working right (returns positive values)
    Papers:
    [1] The Concrete Distribution: A Continuous Relaxation of Discrete Random Variables (Maddison et al, 2017)
    [2] Categorical Reparametrization with Gumbel-Softmax (Jang et al, 2017)
    '''

    def sample(self, sample_shape=torch.Size()):
        '''Gumbel-softmax sampling. Note rsample is inherited from RelaxedOneHotCategorical'''
        u = torch.empty(self.logits.size(), device=self.logits.device, dtype=self.logits.dtype).uniform_(0, 1)
        noisy_logits = self.logits - torch.log(-torch.log(u))
        return torch.argmax(noisy_logits, dim=-1)

    def log_prob(self, value):
        '''value is one-hot or relaxed'''
        if value.shape != self.logits.shape:
            value = F.one_hot(value.long(), self.logits.shape[-1]).float()
            assert value.shape == self.logits.shape
        return - torch.sum(- value * F.log_softmax(self.logits, -1), -1)
```

And here's the LunarLander results. SAC learns to solve it really fast.

[image: LunarLander result]

The full implementation code is in [SLM Lab](https://github.com/kengz/SLM-Lab) at https://github.com/kengz/SLM-Lab/blob/master/slm_lab/agent/algorithm/sac.py

The SAC benchmark results on Roboschool (continuous) and LunarLander (discrete) are shown here: https://github.com/kengz/SLM-Lab/pull/399

Comment: Have you compared the performance of your implementation with the the one proposed by Petros Christodoulou https://arxiv.org/abs/1910.07207 ? In his article he replaces action samplings with direct summations as the action space is discrete and finite. It should help reduce the variance and speed up convergence, I guess.

Comment: is there a reason you return the negative of the sum of negatives? they cancel out, right?

Comment: also, is it assumed that in `log_prob` there is no gradient on value?

Answer (score 2):

There is a paper about SAC with discrete action spaces. It says SAC for discrete action spaces doesn't need re-parametrization tricks like Gumbel softmax. Instead, SAC needs some modifications. please refer to the paper for more details.

[Paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1910.07207) /
[Author's implementation (without codes for atari)](https://github.com/p-christ/Deep-Reinforcement-Learning-Algorithms-with-PyTorch) / 
[Reproduction (with codes for atari)](https://github.com/ku2482/sac-discrete.pytorch)

I hope it helps you.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to put the link of the paper. I edited the answer above.

Answer (score 1):

Probably this [repo](https://github.com/p-christ/Deep-Reinforcement-Learning-Algorithms-with-PyTorch) may be helpful. Description says, that repo contains an implementation of SAC for discrete action space on PyTorch. There is [file](https://github.com/p-christ/Deep-Reinforcement-Learning-Algorithms-with-PyTorch/blob/master/agents/actor_critic_agents/SAC.py) with SAC algorithm for continuous action space and [file](https://github.com/p-christ/Deep-Reinforcement-Learning-Algorithms-with-PyTorch/blob/master/agents/actor_critic_agents/SAC_Discrete.py) with SAC adapted for discrete action space.

Comment: Thank you, I looked at the script and found that there is another paper on SAC. The architecture and the way the loss is calculated is different. I do not quite understand how he calculates the policy_loss in the repo. In the paper he mentioned in the description is the policy_loss (alpha * log(pi) - Q) but he uses (pi * (log(pi) - q_min))

Comment: As I understand, author of repo was guided by [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/reinforcementlearning/comments/bmm1dj/soft_actorcritic_with_discrete_actions/) thread on reddit.

Comment: Also found this [repo](https://github.com/medipixel/rl_algorithms) with discrete SAC ([script](https://github.com/medipixel/rl_algorithms/blob/master/algorithms/sac/agent.py) and appropriate [PR](https://github.com/medipixel/rl_algorithms/pull/83)). The implementation is also on PyTorch and is based on the newest SAC [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1812.05905.pdf), as I understand.

Comment: It seems that the sac_discrete has been removed again. I tried to run the algorithm with cartpole and the CategoricalDistParams. Unfortunately, it does not run without errors

Comment: This repo and corresponding paper is great, though. But I have a thought with large discrete space, e.g. combinatorial optimization problems. These problems usually have very large action space, which is impossible to handle by this solution. I think in that case, we have no choice to use Gumbel softmax solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Pytorch 1.8 has RelaxedOneHotCategorical, this supports re-parameterized sampling using gumbel softmax.

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from torch.distributions import RelaxedOneHotCategorical

    class Policy(nn.Module):
        def __init__(self, input_dims, hidden_dims, actions):
            super().__init__()
            self.mlp = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(input_dims, hidden_dims), nn.SELU(inplace=True),
                                        nn.Linear(hidden_dims, hidden_dims), nn.SELU(inplace=True),
                                        nn.Linear(hidden_dims, out_dims))

        def forward(self, state):
            logits = torch.log_softmax(self.mlp(state), dim=-1)
            return RelaxedOneHotCategorical(logits=logits, temperature=torch.ones(1) * 1.0)
```

```
>>> policy = Policy(4, 16, 2)
>>> a_dist = policy(torch.randn(8, 4))
>>> a_dist.rsample()
tensor([[0.0353, 0.9647],
        [0.1348, 0.8652],
        [0.1110, 0.8890],
        [0.4956, 0.5044],
        [0.6941, 0.3059],
        [0.6126, 0.3874],
        [0.2932, 0.7068],
        [0.0498, 0.9502]], grad_fn=<ExpBackward>)
```